# Make tvOS gamepad buttons send a message just once per physical press of a button

Tags: swift, tvos, gamepad

I am making an Apple TV game and am programming the settings screens.  The problem I am running into is that the Nimbus gamepad is sending multiple button pressed messages when I press the button just once.  I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me if there is a way to make the controller send only one button tapped message when the button is tapped just once.  I mean I would like it is there was a way to have only one message generated after I press a button and release the button.   Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the GameController docs:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamecontroller/gccontrollerbuttoninput?changes=_2

Are you using pressedChangedHandler or valueChangedHandler? IIRC, the Nimbus has pressure-sensitive buttons so you should expect to receive continuously changing values when the button is pressed or released. pressedChangedHandler should only be called when isPressed is toggled.